# How to merge a parent branch while keeping the child branch intact

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I currently have a branch off of master which, for the purposes of this question, we will call "branch A". I want to develop a new feature that builds on code that I wrote in branch A but it's a significant feature so I want to make a new branch. Let's call this new branch "branch B". I need to start working on branch B now but branch A will be merged to master at some point after branch B is created but before branch B is finished. Is there a way to do this so that the branch hierarchy is preserved? Here's a visualisation of what I want:

Before merge:

```
_______ master
  \________ branch A
       \________ branch B
```

After merge:

```
_______ master (with branch A merged)
   \_______ branch B
```

I essentially want my branch structure to remain intact but move up a level.

This is what I don't want to happen:

Before merge:

```
_______ master
  \________ branch A
       \________ branch B
```

After merge:

```
_______ master (with both branch A and branch B merged)
```

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, it can be done very easily since it's the principle of merge in action here.

---

**What to do?**

Just merge `branchA` into `master`, `branchB` will stay out of the scope of this merge.

```
git checkout master
git merge branchA
```

---

**Why?**

Git will search for the merge-base between these two (the most recent commit they share) then apply to the receiving end (here `master`) every commit present in the giving end (here `branchA`) that `master` does not have.

Let's imagine a more detailed example around yours :

```
C1-<-C2-<-C3-<-C4 <<< master
      \
       \
        C5-<-C6-<-C7-<-C8 <<< branchA
                   \
                    \
                     C9-<-C10 <<< branchB
```

When you do `git merge branchA` from your `master` branch, git will determine that the merge-base between these two branches is `C2`. Then it will detect `C5`, `C6`, `C7` and `C8` as the commits absent from `master` but present in `branchA`. `C9` and `C10` have no reason to be included since they're not reachable from `branchA`.

---

**Situation afterwards**

```
C1-<-C2-<-C3-<-C4-<--------C11 <<< master
      \                   /
       \                 /
        C5-<-C6-<-C7-<-C8 <<< branchA
                   \
                    \
                     C9-<-C10 <<< branchB
```

You could or not dispose of your `branchA` after the merge, but in any case `master` will contain* every commit but `C9` and `C10`. (`C11` is the merge commit.)

And you'll be able to go on working on `branchB` then merge it into `master` (or not, for that matter) at some future point.

* *(some people prefer this metaphor to conceptualize branches, but technically it just means that all these commits are reachable from the branch tip, through parent relation)*